# Diseño de Modelo relacional/estructura de base de datos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Estoy diseñando la estructura de una base de datos en un diagrama UML, que se utilizará en un sistema de inventario y registro de actividades, claro, la intención es registrar las actividades relacionandolas a los equipos y que siempre quedé un historial, aparte de una que otra funcionalidad, aunque realmente nunca he diseñado la estructura de una base de datos, solo he trabajado con SQL directamente. 
Pero, me gustaría tener opiniones que personas con más experiencia a ver qué me recomiendan, que está bien y que está mal o hay que modificar. Gracias de antemano.
PD: Los tipos de datos solo los coloque a atributos de algunas entidades, no sé fijen mucho en eso.
[image: Diseño de base de datos - diagrama UML]

Cambios recientes.

Lo modifique ahora enfocado a bases de datos en lugar de UML y realice algunos cambios, como asignarle el tipo de dato a cada atributo, un poco más ordenado especifique claves primarias y foraneas, le asigné cardinalidad debida y el tipo de relación que tienen la entidades entre ellas. Cualquier consejo, algun dato redundante, algún cardinalidad errónea, alguna optimización posible, se agradece.

[image: Diseño de Modelo ER/Estructura de base de datos]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes aprovechar mucho lo que tienes, solo tienes que pensar que tipo de relación tienen tus tablas entre ellas.

Si ya has trabajado con SQL anteriormente te sera muy fácil hacerlo.

Existen principalmente 3 tipos de relación: 1:1, 1:N y N:M

Cuando establezcas una relación (1:1), la foren puedes ponerla donde quieras.

Cuando establezcas una relación (1:N), la tabla que posea el indice fuerte (N) se lleva la foren.

Cuando establezcas una relación (N:M), se debe crear una tabla que relaciones las tablas entre si.

Te paso un ejemplo visual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero que nada, gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder Srsole,  gracias por el consejo y bueno, ya había visto un poco, el tema del modelo ER, solo que me enredaba un al buscar como trabajar con todo, pero bueno aunque claramente no soy un experto, he hecho algunos cambios basándome más en esto y nada, espero este mejor, de todos modos cualquier consejo adicional lo agradecería mucho, alguna redundancia de datos, si se podría optimizar etc.. y bueno, nuevamente gracias y subiré la nueva tabla al post principal editandolo, para que lo puedas ver

Answer (score 1):

primero que todo ha elegio el lenguaje incorrecto, UML es para diagramar software orientado a objetos, si es la primera vez que modela DBs, debe usar un modelo entidad relación, para después pasar a un modelo relacional. Así que primero debe estudiar esa parte, después se dará cuenta que interpretar el modelo relacional va a ser más rápido y puede omitir el modelo entidad relación, para hacer modelos relacionales, puede usar mysql workbench.

Comment: Primero que nada, gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder David, y si tienes razón, UML es para diseñar sofware orientado a objetos, pasa que seguía una guía en la que lo hacían de esa manera con día diagram, pero incluso está app te permite modelar bases de datos, solo que no lo había visto y efectivamente he leído alguna guía acerca del modelo ER, para medio manejar el tema de las entidades, abstractas y concretas, atributos, claves y foraneos y el tema de la cardinalidad... Aunque no se si lo domino del todo pero tengo algúnos cambios en el diagrama antes mostrado, algún consejo 